# How to call asp.net web api method asynchronously in C# web client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an asp.net web application which is using asp.net web api back end. there are several web forms with master data Dropdowns and all the master data taking from web api and binding to Dropdowns. The problem is this takes much time to load all the data. Therefore I need to bind all dropdowns asynchronously without binding one after another. I need to do this with c# web client not with JQuery Ajax requests.

Here is my web api method

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetAllBanks()
 {
        try
        {
            CommonApplicationService masterService = new CommonApplicationService();
            List<Bank> bank = masterService.GetAllBanks();
            return Ok(bank);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return BadRequest();
        }


  }
```

Here is my C# web client's get method.

```
   public static string Get(string url, WebHeaderCollection headerCollection)
    {
        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Headers.Add(headerCollection);

            HttpWebResponse _response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_response.GetResponseStream());

            string response = sr.ReadToEnd();

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Could someone explain me how to do this process asynchronously?

Comment: `GetResponseAsync`

Comment: I want to await until all the drop downs data loaded

Comment: When designing async methods you should always start at the bottom and not in the top (Api). Digg in the masterService.GetAllBanks() until you come to the part that is communicating with the DB. The most modern db clients/frameworks implement Async() methods so look for that and then work your way up to the Api from there.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll()` lets you wait for multiple async tasks.